# Left join vs subquery

Tags: sql

I have the following query with left join can I make this as subquery instead? Will it work faster since it's the same table?
I will only want to get the revenue rows and show revenue2 only for them

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         s_campaign_id,
         SUM(CASE
                WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN '2021-01-31' AND '2021-01-31'
                   THEN f_revenue
                   ELSE 0
             END) AS revenue,
         SUM(CASE
                WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN '2021-01-30' AND '2021-01-30' 
                   THEN f_revenue
                   ELSE 0
             END) AS revenue2
     FROM 
         tbl_reports
     WHERE 
         (d_gen_date >= '2021-01-31'
          AND d_gen_date <= '2021-01-31')
     GROUP BY 
         s_campaign_id) d1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         s_campaign_id,
         SUM(CASE
                WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN '2021-01-30' AND '2021-01-30' 
                   THEN f_revenue
                   ELSE 0
             END) AS revenue2
     FROM 
         tbl_reports
     WHERE 
         (d_gen_date BETWEEN '2021-01-30' AND '2021-01-30')
     GROUP BY 
         s_campaign_id) d2 ON d1.s_campaign_id = d2.s_campaign_id
```

Comment: Which database ? Performance is a tricky thing to do so you need to mention index, database, no of rows and size of table.  Whats the difference between d1.revenue2 and d2.revenue2 ? Looks like you can do this using without sub query/left join.

Comment: You should tag SQL questions always with the DBMS you are using. As SQL features differ a lot in the products, an answer can depend heavily on whether you are using MySQL or SQL Server for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is quite suspicious as you can achieve the desired result using minor changes in first query as follows:

```
  SELECT T.* FROM
  (SELECT s_campaign_id,
         SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date = '2021-01-31' THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue,
         SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date = '2021-01-30' THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue2 
    FROM tbl_reports 
   WHERE (d_gen_date>='2021-01-30' AND d_gen_date<='2021-01-31') 
   GROUP BY s_campaign_id) T
   WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from tbl_reports tt 
                  where t.s_campaign_id = tt.s_campaign_id
                    and tt.d_gen_date ='2021-01-31')
```

Comment: this gets me 206 rows while my query gets me 154 rows

Comment: Ok, Answer is updated. Used EXISTS

Comment: i am missing one row with this query for some reason

Comment: Please check which record is missing and why is it missing? which condition is not satisfying for that record.

Answer (score 0):

just use aggregation and you dont need between cause you are used same date

```
select s_campaign_id,
SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date ='2021-01-31' THEN f_revenue
                ELSE 0
             END) AS revenue,
SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date ='2021-01-30' THEN f_revenue
                ELSE 0
             END) AS revenue2    
FROM   tbl_reports 
WHERE              d_gen_date>='2021-01-30' and  d_gen_date<='2021-01-31'
     GROUP BY 
         s_campaign_id
```

Comment: this gets me 206 rows while my query gets me 154 rows

Answer (score 0):

You are using conditional aggregation, i.e. a condition inside an aggregation function (`SUM(CASE WHEN ... END)`). But because of your `WHERE` clauses, these conditions are either always met or always not met. You can hence simplify your query, because you don't need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT d1.s_campaign_id, d1.revenue, d2.revenue2
FROM
(
  SELECT s_campaign_id, SUM(f_revenue) AS revenue
  FROM tbl_reports
  WHERE d_gen_date = '2021-01-31'
  GROUP BY s_campaign_id
) d1
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT s_campaign_id, SUM(f_revenue) AS revenue2
  FROM tbl_reports
  WHERE d_gen_date = '2021-01-30'
  GROUP BY s_campaign_id
) d2 ON d1.s_campaign_id = d2.s_campaign_id;
```

Or you do use conditional aggregation, but then you don't need two intermediate result sets that you join:

```
SELECT 
  s_campaign_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date = '2021-01-31' THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue,
  SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date = '2021-01-30' THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue2
FROM tbl_reports
WHERE d_gen_date >= '2021-01-30' AND d_gen_date <= '2021-01-31'
GROUP BY s_campaign_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN d_gen_date = '2021-01-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

Either query should benefit from this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON tbl_reports (d_gen_date, s_campaign_id);
```